# Swift: How ARC deals with anonymous objects?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, compiler-optimization, manual-retain-release, swift-compiler

ARC came many years ago to replace painful MRC, but since ARC is only a compiler technique its magic happens during the compile time. So, basically what it does - automatically inserts `retain` and `release` calls where appropriate. So, now comes my question - how ARC deal with the following examples

```
func foo() {
 X().doSomething()
}

func bar() {
 anotherFunc(X())
}
```

Objects are created with `ref count == 1`(as far as I know it, at least in old MRC objc `alloc`, `new`, `copy` where calling `retain`. Please correct me if I'm wrong), so the compiler have to decrease ref count on these objects in order to dealloc them ? But how is this done since there is actually no ref to these objects, they are anonymous ! I assume that compiler may do the following optimisation

```
func foo() {
 let var0001 = X()
 var0001.doSomething()
 var0001.release()
}
```

I mean that compiler will make the reference to the anonymous object so it will be able to call `release` on it. But, I'm not sure that this is exactly how it works! So, can somebody explain please what actually happens in this scenario ?
Kind Regards,
Andre

Comment: You can inspect the generated assembly code on https://swift.godbolt.org :)